# regexp, python: index of last occurrence. Has negative look-behind

Tags: python, regex

I need to get the index of the last occurrence of a regexp.

In the sentence below, I need to get the index of the last period or exclamation point, but not if it's part of a short abbreviation (space-char-period)

```
Great buy w. all amenities! Use on all cars. come on in
```

I can get the index of the first occurrence like this

```
t = u"Great buy w. all amenities! Use on all cars. come on in "
p = "(?<! .)([.] |! )"
i = len(re.compile(p).split(t)[0])
print i
```

That's the exclamation point after "amenities". But I need the period after "cars".

My abbreviation regexp may need some tuning, but the point is that the regexp has a negative look-behind.

I tried using a negative look-ahead but it got complicated and didn't work the way I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over all matches using [`finditer()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.finditer), and pick the last one (using the resulting [`MatchObject`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject)'s [`.start()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start):

```
import re

p = re.compile("(?<! .)([.] |! )")
t = u"Great buy w. all amenities! Use on all cars. come on in "

last = None
for m in p.finditer(t):
    last = m

if last is not None:
    print m.start()
```

prints `43`.

Do note that your regular expression, as it stands, won't work with any punctuation that is the *last* character in your input; if `t` was changed to:

```
t = u"Great buy w. all amenities! Use on all cars. come on in!"
```

the result would still be `43`, and not `55`.You'd need to match punctuation followed by whitespace *or* the end of the string:

```
p = re.compile("(?<! .)([.!](?:\s|$))")
```

This then gives:

```
>>> import re
>>> t = u"Great buy w. all amenities! Use on all cars. come on in!"
>>> p = re.compile("(?<! .)([.!](?:\s|$))")
>>> last = None
>>> for m in p.finditer(t):
...     last = m
... 
>>> if last is not None:
...     print m.start()
... 
55
```

Comment: Fails if the last character of the string is `.` or `!` - if that is a possibility.

Comment: @MikeM: It would for the original regular expression. My point was to demonstrate how to find the last match for any regex search that has multiple matches.

Comment: Fair enough, Martijn. I just couldn't resist - perhaps I should have done.

Comment: @MikeM: You are correct of course, and I've expanded my answer to provide a better regexp for that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to find the index of the last occurrence of `.` or `!`.

```
t = u"Great buy w. all amenities! Use on all cars. come on in "
i = re.search(r"((?<!\s\S)\.|!)[^.!]*$", t)
if i is not None:
    print i.start()
```